# Python Deleting All Folders but not files

Tags: python, shutil

I am looking to write a piece of python code that deletes all folders and their contents, but does not delete individual files.
For example here are some files and folders contained in a directory (Folder B) along with the script file that does the deleting. How do I delete folderA, folderB,folderC,etc, but leave the files?  Thanks

```
/Folder B 
    file.docx
    fileB.docx
    fileC.docx
    pythonDeleteScript.py
    folderA/
    folderB/
    folderC/
    folderD/
```

Comment: [os.path.isdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir) + [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) + [os.rmdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rmdir)

Comment: @Copperfield: You'd want [`shutil.rmtree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) to do this simply when the folders are non-empty. If you're on modern Python, it can simplify to [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) (which covers the combined functionality of `os.listdir` and `os.path.isdir`, but more efficiently)+`shutil.rmtree`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `os.listdir()` to get the contents of the directory, `os.path.isdir(path)` to see if it is a folder, and if it is, `shutil.rmtree(path)` to delete the folder and all its content.